# How to use .or() or T.in in gremlin without doing whole graph scan?

Tags: indexing, titan, gremlin

I'm using Titan 0.5.1 and gremlin and I am trying to query the DB for all vertices that have a type of typeA or TypeB.

I have tried both of these, 
`g.V().has("type" T.in, ["typeA","typeB"])` and 
`g.V().or(_().has("type","typeA"),_().has("type","typeB"))`

And while they both produce the results I want they both involve full graph scans.

If I do them separate
`g.V().has("type","typeA")` and `g.V().has("type","typeB")`
Then the index is hit and full graph scans are not required.  Is there anyway to use the index and perform both queries in one as I need to continue on with more traversing and filtering after I get all vertices of those two types.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but would like to see something that uses fairMerge/exhaustMerge to weave the results together.
    newthing{g.V().has("type","typeA"), g.V().has("type","typeB")}.fairMerge()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should use an index:

```
g.V().has("type" T.in, ["typeA","typeB"])
```

though I think the 0.5.x line had a bug out there for it.  In the mean time you could do:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> ["marko","josh"]._().transform{g.V('name',it).next()}
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I hope the bug gets fixed soon as I prefer using has() to using the work around but for now that will get the job done.

Comment: The issue appears to be closed/fixed - https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/679